# Is this condition useful?

Tags: jquery, conditional-statements

```
var docH = $(document).height(),
    viewPortH = $(window).height(),
    wrapper = $("section"),
    valRight = wrapper.css("right");

  if (docH > viewPortH && valRight != w3) {
    wrapper.stop().animate({
      "right": -w3
    }, 700);
  }
```

I was wondering whether it is useful (performance wise) to have that second condition `valRight != w3` (`w3`is defined earlier in the document). Let's say that the code works flawlessly without it, but I thought it might be useful:

When jQuery reads this and sees that the document is taller than the window, then it will execute the function, even if the `right` value is already `-w3`, which causes some unnecessary overhead. I thought to get by this by the extra condition. But is it useful in this case, or not?

Comment: Usefull or not, this won't change the performance of your script.

Comment: Do you mean `valRight != -w3`?

Comment: @sp00m: Why won't it? In the event `valRight == w3`, it'll stop `stop()` and `animate()` being called.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi : indeed! Thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `!=` against two numbers is considerably quicker than queuing unnecessary animation frames.

However, you could save even more time via;

```
var wrapper = $("section"),
    valRight = wrapper.css("right");

if (valRight != w3) {
  var docH = $(document).height(),
    viewPortH = $(window).height();


  if (docH > viewPortH) {
    wrapper.stop().animate({
      "right": -w3
    }, 700);
  }
}
```

... as you'll stop unnecessary jQuery objects and `height()` calculations in the event `valRight != (-?)w3`.

Comment: Nice find! I always find it hard to find the best, most efficient and quickest way of ordering my if/else statements ... Thanks again!

Comment: Edit: apparently my `else` statement does not work anymore when using this (should have supplied that). Here is my whole case: http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/npVMs/ I swapped the order. So first I check whether or not the height is taller and then whether or not the property equals `-w3`. Does the difference still matter now?

Comment: @BramVanroy: If you're declaring your variables at the top of the function rather than inside the `if`, you're not gaining anything anyway. My approach saved you having to assign the `docH` and `viewPortH` variables.

Comment: But that's the problem with your solution: Once I implement it, the `else` function does not work anymore. (console: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parent' of null`): your solution (does not work, try resizing the window so the scrollbar disappears): http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/npVMs/

Comment: Fixed it by adding "px" value :) `if (valRight != -w3 + "px")`